# Запуск Visual Studio через runas от администратора

Tags: windows, visual-studio

В общем, использую runas с такой конфигурацией:

> C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:"domain\login" /netonly
>   "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"

Таким образом, Visual Studio запускается под другим доменные пользователем не тем, под которым я сижу на ПК => работают всякие ресурсы, которые не доступны из под обычной учеткой.

Вопрос в том, а как мне ко всему выше сказанному запустить вижуалку от администратора?

Т.е я хочу запустить вижуалку из под другой учетки+ иметь права админа на текущем пк.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принципе, косвенно я решил свою проблему.

Я просто в свойствах EXE-файла студии выставил постоянный запуск от админа.

Получается, что команда выше запускает студию под другой учеткой, а параметры файла добавляют к этому еще и запуск от админа.

А еще можно ярлык с командой из вопроса запустить от админа и будет тот же самый результат.